# TideSDK application get all applications from OS

Tags: tidesdk

Is it possible to use tideSDK to check what applications are running in the Operative System?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to write a native app that does that, which you can then call from within TideSDK. You might want to look into using MonoDevelop for that, since you could hit Windows and OSX with the same application.